# "Windows cannot access share" with 0x800704cf error

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, network-shares

I have a simple LAN with file server, called `FILES`, which is a Windows 8.1 Pro machine with a bunch of shared folders. I use several Windows 8.1 Pro and Windows 10 Pro client machines to connect to these shares over Ethernet or WiFi through Netgear R8000 router.

I set up all Windows machines for basic password-based authentication. I.e. all machines have exactly the same set of user accounts with identical passwords. All machines belong to default `WORKGROUP`. Homegroups are disabled. Windows Firewall is turned off on all machines as well. The network is designated as private.

Now, on a client machine I can open File Explorer hit 'Network' and see `FILES` listed as a machine on my network. (Meaning that network discovery works fine.) I can double click on `FILES` icon and immediately see the full list of all available shares on `FILES` (so this part works fine as well).

But then, when I click on a specific share (say, `Storage`), I get an error message

[image]

Trying to click on the same share again (or on other shares) produces the same error. *But it happens only for about 20-40 seconds after the first click.* After that period, the next click suddenly successfully opens the share and everything works fine after that. All other shares on `FILES` also begin working perfectly. Basically, since that moment on everything works as it should.

However, if I leave `FILES` alone for a while and then return back to it, the same behavior reappears again. First click of any of the `FILES` shares generates the above `0x800704cf` error, but after 20-40 seconds everything starts working again.

This behavior is very consistent and easily reproducible. The behavior is the same for wired and wireless clients.

Now, when try to access the same shares by specifying the IP address of `FILES` explicitly (as in `\\192.168.1.3\Storage`), the share always opens successfully without any delay. This suggests that this is some sort of name resolution issue. However, doing `ping FILES` always succeeds instantly, without any errors. Even when File Explorer throws `0x800704cf` for `\\FILES\Storage`, `ping FILES` still works correctly.

Just to test the name resolution theory again, I added `192.168.1.3 FILES` to LMHOSTS file. But it didn't help. The problem is still there, which appears to indicate that this is not a name resolution issue.

So, what else could be the reason for this annoying error? I see it mentioned on the Net quite a few times, but no definitive answer.

P.S. Occasionally, very rarely I get a similar error earlier, when I try to open `FILES` itself: "Windows cannot access \\FILES" (error `0x80070035`). But this is very rare. In 99 cases out of 100 I can open `FILES` successfully and see the list of all shares. The error only occurs when I attempt to access `\\FILES\Storage` (or any other share) and it is `0x800704cf`.

---

In my case

```
netsh int ip reset
```

<strike>saved the day</strike> temporarily seemed to improve the situation. Running it on `FILES` (and then re-entering normal adapter settings) made all shares accessible immediately and reliably. But about a day later the original problem reappeared in its full glory.

Comment: You need something to act as an internal DNS server and / or provide static routes. This thread might help get you started: http://superuser.com/questions/45789/running-dns-locally-for-home-network

Comment: @AthomSfere But why would I need it? An experiment with `ping` shows that name resolution works flawlessly. Also, `lmhosts` should have taken care of any name resolution issues anyway. But the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on a Windows Server in an full AD domain.

The fix that resolved my issue was that my Network Adapter properties did not have "Client for Microsoft Networks" installed.

I did the following:

1. From the Network and Sharing Center click Change Adapter Settings
2. Right Click on Adapter >> Select Properties
3. Check if "Client For Microsoft Networks" is installed? If not;
4. Click Install
5. Double-Click Clients
6. Choose Client for Microsoft Networks
7. Click Ok >> OK
8. Restart the computer

When it came back up I was  able to access the network share.

Found this @ [Since Windows 8.1 Cannot Access Network Shares on Windows Home Server 2011](https://superuser.com/questions/750923/since-windows-8-1-cannot-access-network-shares-on-windows-home-server-2011)

Comment: That's odd. I actually had to **disable** `Client for Microsoft Networks` in order to get rid of the sporadic `0x800704cf` error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding the user's samba credentials in "Windows Credential Manager", after that, samba accessed normally.

You may add the user as "ServerDnsName\Username"...